# How to upgrade crystal report version from 10.5 to 13.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

Can any one give the idea or provide me the steps on how to upgrade the crystal report version v10.5 to v13.0. We have a ASP.net web application and we are currently using Visual Studio 2008. we are having report files(.rpt extension) with the crystal report assembly version as 10.5. Now I want to upgrade the same report files to v13.0.

Can anyone provide me the steps to upgrade v10.5 to v13.0

Answer (score 0):

First off, the later viewer should run your 10.5 reports. As for "upgrading" them, you can upgrade any report by opening and resaving the report in a later version.